# Facing an issue on build after migrating to Webpack v5 from v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

After migrating to webpack 5, and updated the webpack configurations. I'm not able to build anymore, and i'm facing the error below.

```
/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:40
        if (error) throw error;
                   ^

TypeError: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:163:11)
    at Object.resolve (node:path:1098:7)
    at afterResolveFn (/node_modules/offline-plugin/lib/index.js:213:42)
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at /node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:284:30
    at eval (eval at create (/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:591:7
    at /node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:116:11
    at /node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:623:8
    at NormalModuleFactory.resolveRequestArray (/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:988:34)
    at /node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:615:11
    at /node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:116:11
    at /node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:678:9
    at /node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:859:5 {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

```
NodeJs version Node.js v18.12.1

packages versions:
 "webpack": "^5.76.0",
 "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
 "webpack-dev-middleware": "^6.0.1",
 "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.3",
 "webpack-pwa-manifest": "^4.3.0",
```

I tried to update all the loaders to the lates (css-loader, url-loader, style-loader, svg-url-loader, file-loader, etc...)

Faced some issues with my css and svg (not loading), and the build issue didn't changed or fixed.

Comment: And you read through, and applied/followed all the things that https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/ talks about?